# Using a standard deck of cards, what is the probability of drawing 2 cards that sum to 10?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

By standard deck of cards, I mean a 52-card deck used for games like Blackjack and Poker. Also, let's assume Ace can only be 11. So {1,9} is not a possible choice.

Here is my logic:
The total amount of possible 2-card hands I can draw is $C(52,2)$ which is my denominator.
Now, counting all possible hands that sum to 10. I have {2,8}, {3,7}, {4,6}, and {5,5}. I think it makes sense for {2,8}, {3,7}, {4,6} to be handled separately from {5,5} as demonstrated below.

Case {2,8}, {3,7}, {4,6}:
For my first card, I must pick a card out of any of these ranks {2,3,4,6,7,8}. And I have 4 cards in each rank, and I must pick 1 out of my available options. => $C(24,1)$.

For the second card, I must pick a card out of the rank that completes the sum (i.e. if 8 was 1st, then I must pick 2). There should only be 1 rank, which has 4 cards => $C(4,1)$.

Case {5,5}:
For both cards, they must be of the same rank, 5, and there are only 4 available in the deck => $C(4,2)$.

Using my above logic I get this equation:

$( C(24,1)*C(4,1) + C(4,2) ) / C(52,2) )$

However, this answer is incorrect. Where did I go wrong in my logic?

Comment: There are some cases which are counted twice in your method. say C(24,1)C(4,1) has a case when we choose 2 then 8 which is same as choosing 8 first then 2

Comment: @Rick Can you please expand on your comment? I'm not sure I understand. The answer for $P(21) = C(16,1) * C(4,1) / C(52,2)$. 16 possible choices for the first card (10,J,Q,K) * 4 possible choices for the second (A). Why would Case 1 be different than this case?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @Mathsmerizing! I still don't know the answer, but I'll go through my logic again with this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, first let us choose any one from your 3 groups {2,8}, {3,7}, {4,6},  and then choosing one card from each set. So, we will get C(3,1)C(4,1)C(4,1)+C(4,2) for {5,5}.
Thus, the required probability=$\frac{54}{C(52,2)}$

Comment: Yes, i meant 3 but somehow wrote 4 and solved :). Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1):

As @Mathsmerizing has said, you have double-counted the first part.

You want $\frac {\frac {C(24,1)*C(4,1)}{2}+C(4,2)}{C(52,2)}$

You don't need to halve $C(4,2)$ because that has already been halved in its own calculation.